How to convert point cloud to textured mesh model or colored mesh model in python
I'm trying to convert a 2d image of a leaf

into a 3d textured mesh model or colored mesh model using python in colab. I followed this guy tutorial. But i am facing some problem when trying to convert a point cloud of my image into a 3d mesh model. When converting my image to cloud point the color or texture are still there and can be visualized using open3d
o3d.visualization.draw_plotly([pcd_raw])


But after converting to a 3d mesh model. The color or texture from the cloud point are not present. The result mesh model is only a plain gray model.
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson(pcd, depth=10, n_threads=1)[0]
mesh.rotate(rotation, center=(0, 0, 0))
o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh('/content/leaf.obj', mesh)
o3d.visualization.draw_plotly([mesh])


Hope you guy can help me solve this problem.
A 3d mesh model that have color or texture obtain from the cloud point
